# 80's movie with creepy dog?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, ghost

This might be a long shot with how little I remember of the movie.  I only remember one scene, where  a small dog flies through a window knocking a man out.  Then it shows the man laying there while the camera pans away to show a dog staring at him menacingly. The movie either had to do with a spirit, parasite, or alien that could take over animals' bodies

Comment: Is it a horror or a comedy? Sounds hilarious!

Comment: Sounds a little bit like "The Thing" ?

Comment: @Stark07 the infected huskies never actually do anything in The Thing once they get infected. They don't attack anyone or jump through any windows. And you definitely wouldn't call them _small_.

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah true... Dunno that was the first *thing* that came to my mind :P

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [Suspiria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspiria) directed by the great Dario Argento, containing this scene with a seeing-eye dog attacking and killing its master. Suspiria is about a dance school which is a front of a coven of witches.

Warning: this is a horror movie and the video below is meant to be scary and possibly NSFW as a result.

Answer (score 1):

[Baxter](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Baxter_%28film%29) maybe?

"The title character is a murderous white Bull Terrier who tells the story of his search for a proper master in voice-over narration."

Answer (score 1):

Could it be "Vampire Dog"? 
It has a small dog. 
The dog moves fast enough to appear to be flying.
He knocks a guy over into a vat of jello.
It's eyes are creepy.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't a dog infected by the parasite in *The Hidden* (1987)? Not sure about the flying through the window part, but the rest fits.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but *maybe* you're thinking of [Night of the Creeps (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091630/).

[Plot Summary](http://gbhbl.com/2013/08/03/movie-review-night-of-the-creeps-1986/)

The details which fit:

- Alien parasites which can take over bodies (both human and animal)
- There's a creepy parasite-infected dog which is pivotal to the movie

The details which don't fit:

- I don't believe the dog ever flies through a window. It does cause a bus crash and it does look menacingly at a couple of people.

[image: The dog]